# CSS Columns but with Rows?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

With CSS Regions being removed from the spec, is there now any known way to flow content into a series of rows, instead of a series of columns?
For example, rotating the page 90 degrees clockwise, and then rotating each individual column 90d ccw?

Answer (score -1):

not sure I understand what you need, but here is a starting point

```
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid .column-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid .column-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
}

.grid .column-4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 25%;
}
```